# Dashboard- To display how many new records are made

Tags: dashboard, count

Is there a way to display reports in a seven-day week format?

> Example: Monday - 100 records
>
> Tuesday - 60 records etc.. until Sunday

To be displayed in bar chart. Is COUNT possible for salesforce? Or are there any other way?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you cannot sort date fields by day of the week in reports. One option you have is create a custom formula field on the underlying object called as 'Day' with formula as -

**CASE( MOD(DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) - DATE(1900, 1, 7), 7), 0, "Sunday", 1, "Monday", 2, "Tuesday", 3,"Wednesday", 4, "Thursday", 5, "Friday", 6, "Saturday","Error")**

Then you can group by this field on the summary report and use the same in dashboard. Also ensure that you select appropriate range on the Report like - 
**This Week, Last Week** or **Last 7 days** whatever suits your need.
At last you can use this report in dashboard in bar chart component.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a summary report and use createdDate for row grouping and it will show record count at all summary level.

[image]

[image]